# Scala: Equivalent of numpy.where()[0]

Tags: scala

In python, if x is a numpy array, I just have to write this:

```
    np.where(x > 0)[0]
```

in order to get the indices of the negative entries. Is there an equivalent functionality in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i've used recently is that if x is an array, I can use:

```
val indexes = x.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 > 0).map(_._2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [findAll](http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/#breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix) method. An example:

```
val matrix = DenseVector.horzcat(DenseVector(0.0, -1.0), DenseVector(0.0, 0.0))
val idxs = matrix.findAll(_ < 0.0) // Vector((1, 0))
```